# Expanding upon the Bootstrap mobile navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap I have a standard collapsible navigation.

When the mobile navigation is open I want to add an extra element to the top of the navigation, essentially as quick links to key areas.

I have added the below picture to illustrate my idea.

[image: My design idea]

Essentially I have the Bootstrap navigation but is it feasible just to add a DIV or include a file at the correct viewport, in order to add the extra grid above the navigation.

UPDATE

So far I have the following using the advice given, I think now all that's required is to remove padding, as the navigation is in a col-xx-12.

[image]

Comment: Try using the `hidden-xs` / `hidden-lg` classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap responsive utility classes such as `.hidden-xs` .

This allows to hide and show the divs based on the screen dimension.

**[Refer here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)**

Comment: This seems entirely feasible, I will see what I can come up with and post my result.